# How do I specify the admin_level for a search?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have this query to collect all of the cities within Florida:

```
[out:json];
area['admin_level'='4']['name'='Florida'];
(relation['admin_level'='8'](area););out;
```

There are two instance of Florida at `admin_level` 4, though:

- [Florida, United States](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=198182241)
- [Florida, Uruguay](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=198200612)

You can see how it returns cities in both Floridas [here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/LlK) (you just have to switch to the Data tab and then click the Run button).

How would I rewrite this query to only query the Florida within the United States?
I have 65 other searches that I have to do with similar duplication issues, so a query that I can swap out e.g. a `name` value for each one would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a look at the corresponding relations for [Florida, UY](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1635164) and [Florida, US](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/162050) you can see that there are various additional [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) such as `is_in:country_code` and `ISO3166-2`. You can use one of them to limit the query to a specific country:

```
[out:json];
area['is_in:country_code'='US']['admin_level'='4']['name'='Florida'];
(relation['admin_level'='8'](area););
out;
```

Comment: Thank you! By any chance, do you know how likely it is that regions have the `is_in:country_code` tag on them? No worries if all you can do is shrug at this question - I know how vast OSM data is.

Comment: It looks like there are _some_ Regions without this relation e.g. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4734547#map=8/32.419/-6.279 ... I'll need to figure out how to handle those (or figure out a different way that handles all cases, like your bounding box idea).

Comment: Apologies, I'm learning all of this structure as I go. I just realized that I can split the `ISO3166-2` value on the `-`, and take the first part as the country code. It _looks_ like all Regions include that data...

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: I removed the second example. Combining an area with a bounding box is not supported, i.e. adding that additional bounding box has no impact at all on the query, it simply gets ignored.